# how is it beneficial to Derive a formula for the maximum likelihood and apply it to a dataset

Tags: maximum-likelihood, exponential-distribution

What is the benefit of applying the following on the data set?

If I have a data set that is distributed as follows:
[image]

after calculating the Maximum of logarithm of the likelihood function and applying it to the data according to the equation:
[image]

The distribution is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Please explain how you computed the "New Values of X."

Comment: I calculated labmda as the reciprocal of the mean of the original dataset. Then I applied the f(x) rule shown above to every element of the dataset.

Comment: That gives you a *probability density*, not a dataset!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the OP hit by accident on **one more special property of the Exponential distribution**.
The OP's second diagram is the *empirical frequency function*  of the random variable

$$Y = f_X(X),\;\;\; X \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$$

And it does look like the empirical frequency from a Uniform distribution, right? But, we get the Uniform if we consider the random variable $Z = F_X(X)$, where $F_X$ is the distribution function, not the density...

Well, this is the special property of the Exponential distribution. Consider the random variable $Y= f_X(X)$. To apply the change-of-variable rule, we have $X = f^{-1}(Y)$ and

$$f_Y(y) = \left|\frac{df^{-1}(y)}{dy}\right|\cdot f_X(f_X^{-1}(y))$$

Now by the inverse function theorem,

$$\left|\frac{df^{-1}(y)}{dy}\right| = \frac 1 {\left|f'_X(f^{-1}(y))\right|}$$

while also $$f_X(f_X^{-1}(y)) = y$$ so

$$f_Y(y) = \frac {y}{\left|f'_X(f^{-1}(y))\right|}$$

Now, whenever $|f'| = f$ we get

$$f_Y(y) = \frac {y}{y} = 1,\;\;\; \implies Y \sim U(0,1)$$

i.e. $Y$ is a Uniform $(0,1)$, as if we have considered the $Z = F_X(X)$ rv. And when do we get $|f'| = f$? When $f(x) = e^{-x}$, i.e. when the $X$ variable follows an Exponential distribution with rate/scale parameter equal to unity.

When $X \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda),\;\; \lambda \neq 1$we get $|f'| = \lambda f$, and the result generalizes to

$$f_Y(y) = \frac {y}{\lambda y} = \frac 1 {\lambda},\;\;\; \implies Y \sim U(0,\lambda)$$